# Error in adding external jars

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Im a begginer in java and im using eclipse (if it is relevant). 
I recently tried to work with an external Jar (Std), and i keep having the following error in each attempt to run my program no matter what i do. 
The error:

```
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: StdOut
 at LocalMaxFinder.main(LocalMaxFinder.java:11)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: StdOut
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 ... 1 more
 `
```

The most minimal code that i tried to run that show me that error was:

```
 import libraries.*;
 public class Test {
 public static void main (String[]args) { 
 StdOut.print("Enter Integer"); 
    int x= StdIn.readInt ();
   }
 }
```

- "libraries" is the name of the Jar file that includes StdIn, StdOut, StdDraw and StdAudio
- Before i turned to here i viewed recent questions about that issue and tried every tutorial i found about adding external jars, but im still receiving that same error.
- I also tried every method in that guide: 
  http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)
- I uploaded an image of the project's current path.
- As i said before, Im new to java so i hope i gave you all the necessary         details for you to help me with solving that problem.

Thanks alot for any kind of help.

[The current project's path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hinw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not running the project you are currently looking at.

According g to your stack trace the problem originates in a method max() which is not present in your current project

Right click on the file test.java and select run as java application.

Your run menu most likely Hassan old entry of a previous project.

Answer (score 0):

The error is complaining about the *class* StdOut that is referenced in LocalMaxFinder, in the main() method on line 11 >.>

I don't see the source code for the actual library classes, but my guess is the package name is incorrect. Java (by convention) uses a naming scheme that mirrors the directory structure of the class files, not the name of the actual jar file that contains them. That part is quite irrelevant, assuming the jar file is on the classpath.

To understand what I am describing in detail it is probably best to download some open-source code, for example from Apache, and look at the folder structure and the line at the top of the source code in the .java file that declares the package. If it is 'package com.foo.bar.baz' for example, it would be in the source folder, in com/foo/bar/baz. If the package name is incorrect it will give you this misleading error that the class can not be found.

Do you have the source code for those classes?

If not, there is a command line utility included in the jdk called javap that should be able to help.